# Get total addind one checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

im calculating the total price based in twoo selection boxes, but now i need to add a optional checkbox. When a user check the box it adds a extra 45 €. But i have no idea how can i make the checkbox add inside a different event. To better explain above i leave example of my code.

```
$("#typeRoom").change(function(){

                          if($(this).val() == "Single room" && $("#hotel option:selected").val() == "Hotel A") {
                            $('#bookprice').html(67).append("€").append(" (Breakfast included)"); 

                            if($("#dinner").is(':checked')){    
                             var din = 45;
                            }else{var din = 0;}


                            var totalPrice = 67 + 195 + din;
                            $('#total').html(totalPrice).append("€");
                          }
```

I have to have a way in insert above the "if(..#dinner".." dinner code the "$("#typeRoom").change(function(){" to autoupdate the total price, but it doesnt work.

Can someone tell me is there a way.

Comment: Please review your grammar and code formatting, both can be improved. When you say "it doesn't work" try to explain what you expect to happen and what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the din variable twice! try the following:

```
$("#typeRoom").change(function(){

                          if($(this).val() == "Single room" && $("#hotel option:selected").val() == "Hotel A") {
                            $('#bookprice').html(67).append("€").append(" (Breakfast included)"); 
                            var din = 0;
                            if($("#dinner").is(':checked')){    
                             din = 45;
                            }


                            var totalPrice = 67 + 195 + din;
                            $('#total').html(totalPrice).append("€");
                          }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: But this still dont resolve my issue, because the total price doesnt update of i check after selecting the rooms, is not auto updating in real time

Comment: I suggest add all the code in a funcation and call it from each event, like following:           'code' function CalculateCost() { ... add all the existing code here } then on each event like $("#typeRoom").change(function(){ CalculateCost(); })